# Is there a way to to draw an arc beginning from specific radious

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I am trying to find the arc of an inner circle using `UIBezierPath`. Here is my code `

```
    line1.addLine(to: center)
    line1.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: self.frame.size.height/2, startAngle: CGFloat(45.0).toRadians(), endAngle: CGFloat(315).toRadians(), clockwise: false)
    UIColor(red: 0.6, green: 0.8157, blue: 0.4314, alpha: 1.0).setFill()
    line1.fill()`
```

Here the line1 is `UIBezierPath` center is the centre of UIView which I am subclassing. I don't want to mask this since I will make this radios based on the percentage

The output which I get from this code is
[image]

What I was expecting is like
[image]

Comment: You have three options: 
1. (and easiest) Add the inner circle last, it will cover your BezierPath 
2. Don't fill your drawing, but the line. The width of the line needs to be calculated. if you have the innerCircleRadius(iCR) and the otherCircleRadius(oCR) your new radius will be (iCR + oCR) / 2 and the line width will (iCR + oCR) / 4 
3. Draw a new shape which has an arc at the outer end and one at the inner end. This requires a bit more coding

Comment: @baronfac Not getting exactly

Comment: can you show me the code of the complete drawing?

Comment: I can share you the file can you send me your email ID @baronfac

Comment: You have two options: 1. As @baronfac said, accommodate your drawing sequences. 2. separate your drawing components on different layers, and then adjust your layer’s z property. This maybe more extensible.

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice thing about `UIBezierPath` and `.addArc(...)`

If we add a *clockwise* arc at radius1, from startAngle to endAngle, then add a *counter-clockwise* arc at radius2, swapping startAngle and endAngle, then close the path... the "sides" are automatically added and we get the shape you're looking for.

So, we can use two shape layers. One for the circles and one for the "arc wedge."

Sample custom view class:

```
class ApproachView: UIView {

    // so we can change these properties at run-time
    
    public var totalDegrees: Double = 55 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    public var circlesStrokeColor: UIColor = .lightGray {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    public var arcStrokeColor: UIColor = .lightGray {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    public var arcFillColor: UIColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0) {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    public var circlesStrokeWidth: CGFloat = 2 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    public var arcStrokeWidth: CGFloat = 2 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    private let circlesLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    private let arcLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() -> Void {
        layer.addSublayer(circlesLayer)
        layer.addSublayer(arcLayer)
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        circlesLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        circlesLayer.strokeColor = circlesStrokeColor.cgColor
        arcLayer.fillColor = arcFillColor.cgColor
        arcLayer.strokeColor = arcStrokeColor.cgColor
        circlesLayer.lineWidth = circlesStrokeWidth
        arcLayer.lineWidth = arcStrokeWidth

        // stroke is drawn on centerline, so
        //  inset the drawing area by one-half the line width
        let drawRect = bounds.insetBy(dx: arcStrokeWidth * 0.5, dy: arcStrokeWidth * 0.5)
        
        // outer radius is one-half the width of the view
        let outerRadius = drawRect.width * 0.5
        
        // adjust insets as desired
        let middleCircleRect = drawRect.insetBy(dx: drawRect.width * 0.15, dy: drawRect.width * 0.15)
        let innerCircleRect = drawRect.insetBy(dx: drawRect.width * 0.35, dy: drawRect.width * 0.35)

        var pth: UIBezierPath!
        
        pth = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: middleCircleRect)
        pth.append(UIBezierPath(ovalIn: innerCircleRect))
        
        circlesLayer.path = pth.cgPath
        
        // we want the arc to be centered at 3 o'clock
        let startDegrees = -totalDegrees / 2.0
        let endDegrees = startDegrees + totalDegrees
        
        // convert to radians
        let startAngle = startDegrees * .pi / 180
        let endAngle = endDegrees * .pi / 180

        pth = UIBezierPath()
        
        // add a clockwise arc with outer radius
        pth.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY), radius: outerRadius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
        // add a counter-clockwise arc with radius from the inner circle rect
        pth.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY), radius: innerCircleRect.width * 0.5, startAngle: endAngle, endAngle: startAngle, clockwise: false)
        // close the arc path
        pth.close()
        
        arcLayer.path = pth.cgPath
    }
    
}
```

and example controller:

```
class ApproachTestVC: UIViewController {
    
    let approachView = ApproachView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        approachView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(approachView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            approachView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            approachView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            approachView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            approachView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: approachView.widthAnchor),
        ])
        
        approachView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.2, alpha: 1.0)
        view.backgroundColor = .black
    }
    
}
```

gives us this output:

[image]